# comparing two doubles in the latest visual studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013

In our product code we are substracting the two double variables value1 and value2 and the result is compared with EPSILON, its value is 10e-6.as shown below

```
return ( fabs(value1 - value2) <= EPSILON ) ? true : false;
```

Now this was working perfectly fine in windows 7(VS 2008). Recently we moved to windows 10(VS 2013) because of this its breaking.After my investigation on this I found out that in windows 10 operation on doubles leads to change in the precision value compared to earlier versions.

TO fix this issue I changed EPSILON to 10e-4. After doing this though this one got fixed but some other code is breaking where i am using EPSILON.

what can I do to fix this problem ? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You know, that line is the same as `return fabs(value1 - value2) <= EPSILON;`

Comment: Yes it is, Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the strict IEEE fp compiler option or is that what fails?

Comment: It works fine in VS2015. Show [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: 2013 is not the latest, VS2015 update 3 has been out for a while

Comment: I strongly doubt if it is really precision of double got changed.  Any proof on it?